# Can't get photo printed after camera shot

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make photo that shot to be printed on profile page. Though I get the uri of the photo none was printed. I am using [camerja example of this page](https://github.com/expo/camerja)

```
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.shotPhoto.bind(this)}>
        <Image source={this.props.userpicture != null ? this.props.userpicture : require('../../images/resimyok.png')} />
        <Text>Shot a Photo</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

the returning photo.uri is

file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540programci.yilmaz%252Fkpbduser/photos/Photo_2.jpg

What warning message I got is:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.
```

[image: Before getting image url from camera the profile page]

[image: After getting image url from camera the profile page]

The page from picture uri returning back

```
takePicture = async function() {
if (this.camera) {
  const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };

  this.camera.takePictureAsync().then(data => {
    FileSystem.moveAsync({
      from: data.uri,
      to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${this.state.photoId}.jpg`,
    }).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        photoId: this.state.photoId + 1,
      });
      Vibration.vibrate();
      Actions.hesabim({userpicture: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${this.state.photoId}.jpg`});
    });
  });
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Rewrite Your Code, Must be added **uri** on url request passing time.

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.shotPhoto.bind(this)}>
    <Image source={this.props.userpicture != null ? uri:this.props.userpicture : require('../../images/resimyok.png')} />
    <Text>Shot a Photo</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but putting ***uri:*** in front of this.props.userpicture make syntax error.

Comment: thank you. you were correct but I am not smart to get even answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image style={{height: 200, width: 150}} source={{uri: this.props.userpicture} != null ? {uri: this.props.userpicture} : require('../../images/resimyok.png') } />
```

solved my problem though this time not showing default image.